Nextjs error - React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object
I have created a component library using rollup. It's exporting one component let's say Basic.
import Image from "next/image";

type BasicProps = {
  logoSrc: string;
};

export default function Basic({ logoSrc }: BasicProps) {
  return (
    <Image src={logoSrc} alt="Logo" width={74} height={37} priority />
  );
}

When I am using this library in another project -
import Basic from "ui-library/Basic";

<Basic logoSrc="/images/new-logo-black.png" />

image is present in the /public of the extending repo.
On running next dev build is failing with logs -

Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in
components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
object.
at Basic (/Users/Documents/work/code/node_modules/ui-library/dist/atoms/Basic/index.js:7:22)

I have tried many things like adding next.config.js file in the component library, and adding images there but nothing worked. Although it logging a type issue but it doesn't seem to be a type issue.
PS: nextjs is added as a peer deps in the component library.
Could you please advise how to fix it?
